# To add color for textInput in Flash?

Tags: flash, components, textinput

I  have an issue with applying backgroundColor to a TextInput component in Flash. I have a MoveClip called LastLayer; in that Layer i designed the TextInput by using components. Now I want to add the background color for the TexInput. Anyone guide me. How can i add the background color? Thanks in Advance!

txtUser is the instance name for my TextInput component. I tried this code, but it does not work:

```
txtUser.setStyle("backgroundColor", "#000000"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
tf.size = 25;
tf.color = 0xFF0000;
var ti:TextInput = new TextInput();
ti.textField.background=true;
ti.textField.backgroundColor = 0xffcc00;
ti.x = 100;
ti.y = 100;
ti.width = 200;
ti.height = 30;
ti.text = "your text here";
ti.setStyle("textFormat", tf);
addChild(ti);
```

Comment: ok i Changed the Text in Many Places,If i do like This i Cannot Display the Text .Because i added the Child once only.

Comment: i design the TextInput By using Components,my id of Text Input is txtUser. And i tried this code.txtUser.setStyle("backgroundColor", "#000000"));

Comment: `txtUser.textField.background=true;
txtUser.textField.backgroundColor = 0x000000;`